# jQuery toggle and functions

Tags: jquery, function, toggle

Please take a look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wWHz4/

This is what I made so far with my little bit of jQuery knowledge. I want the following:

When I click* on a button of a selected title, the other titles have to fade or toggle* away. Then animate* the selected title to the left (instead of static jumping), then show* the content of that selected title to the front and change* the button name from 'more...' to 'back'. When I click* on back I want the content to fade* away, animate the selected title back to his position* and bring up the other titles back to place*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working like how I wanted it to be:

```
$('.group .title > div a.button').click(function() {

    var self = this;
    var speed = 500;
    var indexcount = $(self).parent().index() + 1;
    var subcontent = $('.content').find('.columns:nth-child(' + indexcount + ')');

    if ($(self).parent().siblings().is(":visible")) {
        $(self).text('back');
        $(self).parent().siblings().toggle(speed);
        subcontent.delay(speed).toggle("slide", speed);

    } else {
        $(self).text('more');
        subcontent.toggle("slide", speed, function() {
            $(self).parent().siblings().toggle(speed);
        });

    }

});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wWHz4/

Answer (score 2):

Replace this with js code

```
$('.group .title > div a.button').click(function() {
    if ($(this).parent().siblings().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).text('back');
    } else {
        $(this).text('more');
    }
    $(this).parent().siblings().slideToggle("slow");
    var indexcount = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    $('.content').find('.columns:nth-child('+indexcount+')').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for looking! Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but that content needs to be hidden until a Title is selected. It's part of the Title's content ;-) I want that to fade or toggle in somehow. Put it like this: Select the first div of a Title, show the first div of the Content, second and so on. Would you mind taking a look at that? Thnx!

Comment: i m not clear what you are talking about. but once try this code and then let me know if any issue.

Comment: +1! The only last thing now is that it works to static. I want something like this effect using on the Quicksand plugin when selecting a filter type: http://razorjack.net/quicksand/. Or do I want too much now..? Otherwise I'll accept your answer anyways, thnx!

Comment: i can only tell you that i think you can do this with jquery easing effects. i suggest dont use effects for this. the simple slidetoggle is better then other effects.

Comment: Thnx for the tip! I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

To toggle text you can do like this

```
$('.group .title > div a.button').click(function(){
    $(this).html(($(this).html() == "more...")?"back":"more...");
    $(this).parent().siblings().slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).parent().parent().siblings().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Everything else is working in your demo

Answer (score 0):

You can change the properties of the `<a>` tags using jquery `.html()`  [ http://api.jquery.com/html/ ] function also you can place a `<div>` which contains the full text and toggle the state of `display` of that div from `none` to `block` and back to show the full text.

You can have a look at the accordian code using jquery which does something similar to what you want: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/